# How to set alternate colors for ListView items in QML

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to assign 2 colors to the alternate ListView items in QML? I want to color 1st list item as black, then 2nd list item as blue, then 3rd item as black, then 4th item as blue and so on...

How to achieve this thing in qml? Please share your thoughts. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the **index** property of the delegate to determine if this delegate element is even or odd and use that to change the color of the delegate.

```
ListView {
  anchors.fill: parent
  model: 3

  delegate:
    Rectangle {
        width: 20
        height: 30
        color: index % 2 == 0 ? "blue" : "black"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like the following in my code. Because I needed the same styling at different place in the code. So I just created a function.

```
 ListView {
      anchors.fill: parent
      model: 3

      delegate:
        Item{
           function altColor(i) {
              var colors = [ "#E4DDE8", "#00000000" ];
              return colors[i];
           }
           Rectangle {
              width: 20
              height: 30
              color: altColor(index % 2)
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "model.index" - it's exactly the same, but makes your code much more easy to understood.
BTW, because of that

> var colors = [ "#E4DDE8", "#00000000" ];

every time your "altColor" will be called, new array will be created. Very inefficient. Move array declaration to list view:

```
property var colors: ["#E4DDE8", "#00000000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is already answer, you can still define a property for the Listmodel that keeps the color

```
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel

    ListElement {
        name: "Apple"
        cost: 2.45
        elementColor: "red"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Orange"
        cost: 2.45
        elementColor: "black"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Banana"
        cost: 2.45
        elementColor: "gray"
    }
}
```

And display it in the delegate:

```
Rectangle{
    anchors.fillIn:parent
    color: elementColor
}
```